# The QVW File Size Is Larger While Using Cube Data

Tags: sql-server, ssas, business-intelligence, qlikview

I've made two QlikView (two .qvw files) reports which have almost the same content.
One loads data from Data Warehouse using 'Microsoft OLE DB Provider for SQL Server'.
Another one load data from Cube using 'Microsoft OLE DB Provider for Analysis Services'.

However, the file's size with Cube data is much larger than the file with DW data.
I want to know why this happened.

Thanks for attention.

Comment: I suggest taking a look into the data. Is there a difference in column, row or table count? Are the data types different?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Define `almost the same content` :)

QlikView/QlikSense file size are depending on the number of the columns and the **distinct values** in them.

In general Qlik do not store all the data as it is. Instead it stores the data as lists of distinct values and memory pointers and thats how the data model is build.

For example:

If you have two fields in the database (both with 1M rows) - one with `timestamp` values and the other with only `date` values.

In Qlik, the app with the `timestamp` values will be bigger than the `date` app because `timestamp` field have a lot of non distinct values (lets say 80% are non distinct) and `date` have a lot of distinct values (let say 80% are distinct) and Qlik stores only the distinct values in the background.

In the example above you will end with `timestamp` file being saved with 800k rows (80% non distinct) and `date` file with 200k (80% distinct) rows although in the database having both fields with 1M rows.

Im simplifying it, but in general - less fields with high number of distinct values will produce smaller files. Adding 1-2 more columns with a lot non-distinct values can make the file size quite different (especially with bigger datasets).

Real example:

- [SO_47650951_1.qvw](https://drive.google.com/open?id=1mDP5C524mNL_jgBiyhyTHLNaAB__eVGh) - contains 1 field with "1M" rows. The values in it are `floor( rand() * 100)` (1,2,3,4 ... 100) and file size is **968Kb**
- [SO_47650951_2.qvw](https://drive.google.com/open?id=197_yRdqQRPejIKjOjSAT84mp9DzjREFB) - contains 1 field with "1M" rows. The values in it are `rand()` (0.70505229476839, 0.22396470652893, 0.59824940375984 etc) and file size is **7,2Mb**
  "

Comment: Does it also because the MDX query results' columns contain more contents like member properties since data in Cubes are multidimensional?

Answer (score 0):

Stefan's answer is excellent but I wanted to add my own two cents after encountering similar behaviour.

When you import data from an Analysis services cube you will most likely be picking up the dimension hierarchies as well as the distinct elements.

For example a query of SQL server may return 5 dates however in an analysis services cube there may be 50 related records as the dates can roll up to weeks, months, quarters, years, etc and all of these create a distinct point if included in the export.

Rod